# Can anyone help me understand threading for my program?

Tags: android, multithreading

I asked for help from you guys on a program, and it seems it will work. if I can get threading/asynctask to work. I tried to work on threading already and I didn't get it to work. The reason why I am  trying to do threading is because my program crashes when I load it, and basically what its suppose to do is to send an email if someone is calling, because I always misplace my phone or keep it on silent, and I am not aware of it.

**Service-**

```
    public class Callservice extends Service {

    PhoneStateListener listener;
    TelephonyManager tm;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service has started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            listener = new MyphoneStateListener();
            tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            tm.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);



    }

        public class MyphoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
        {
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
            {
                 switch (state) {  
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:   
                        break;  
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING: 
                       sendemail(); 
                        break;  
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:  
                    default:  
                        break;  
                    }  
                    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);  
                }
            }

            private void sendemail()
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("message/rfc822");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL , new String[]{"random@gmail.com"});
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT , "phone is ringing");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT , "email successfully sent");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "send mail..."));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email has been sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    try
                    {
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send Email..."));
                    }
                    catch(android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex)
                    {

                    }
            }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

**Activity-**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    Callservice callservice = new Callservice();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        callservice.onCreate();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: here ya go. http://pastebin.com/GnyKatuS

Comment: @user1884552 : what is onCreate(MainActivity.java:26) line your Activity?

Comment: @user1884552 : you are not showing relevant code so post both Activity and Service code here

Comment: in my main activity is Callservice.onCreate();(I do believe this is the problem as to why it is crashing. IDK how else to call that class to execute it on start up without being on the UI thread)

Comment: @user1884552 : i'm confused why you want to implement threading/asynctask in your Application because you are not doing any heavy task in Ui Thread you are just starting Intentlauncher for sending email

Comment: idk If I need to thread, I figured I had to. anyways I posted the main activity at the top.

Comment: @user1884552 : can you plz make me clear what you want when you want to send mail ?

Comment: @user1884552 : see [this](http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/get-phone-state-when-someone-is-calling_22.html) tutorial this will solve your issue

Comment: @user1884552: You have to show the error report to make it easier for other to find the problem.

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj I posted pastebin earlier of the logcar. prosper the app crashes when I call my phone, so, I will check out that link you sent, and see if I can get it working.

Comment: @user1884552 : yes i'm sure this will work first implement it in your current code

Comment: That link didn't help at all, thanks anywas. :)

Answer (score 4):

Change MainActivity activity as for starting Service from Activity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //Callservice callservice = new Callservice();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startService(new Intent(this,Callservice.class));
    }
   // your code here...
```

and make sure you have added your Service in `AndroidManifest.xml` as:

```
 <service android:name=".Callservice" />
```